# Kotlin Firebase Realtime Database correct return value for setValue() in MVVM

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, mvvm

What would be the correct return value of my `setMyBirthday` function in the `HomeRepository` class for the code to work? Void doesn't seem to be the right return value.

Fragment:

```
private fun HomeViewModel.setupObserver() {
    myBirthday.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { response ->
        when(response) {
            is Resource.Error -> {
                response.message?.let { message ->
                    Log.e(TAG, "An error occurred: $message")
                }
            }
            is Resource.Loading -> {
                binding.buttonChangeBirthday.isClickable = false
            }
            is Resource.Success -> {
                binding.buttonChangeBirthday.isClickable = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HomeViewModel:

```
val myBirthday: MutableLiveData<Resource<Void>> = MutableLiveData()
fun setMyBirthday(birthday: String) = viewModelScope.launch {
    try {
        myBirthday.postValue(Resource.Loading())
        val response = homeRepository.setMyBirthday(birthday)
        myBirthday.postValue(Resource.Success(response))
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        myBirthday.postValue(Resource.Error(e.message!!))
    }
}
```

HomeRepository:

```
    suspend fun setMyBirthday(birthday: String) =
    databaseReference
        .child("users")
        .child(myUserID)
        .child("birthday")
        .setValue(birthday)
        .await()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What would be the correct return value of my function in the HomeRepository class for the code to work? Void doesn't seem to be the right return value.

Indeed [Void](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/lang/Void) is the type of object the `setMyBirthday` function returns. So your function should look like this:

```
//                                            
suspend fun setMyBirthday(birthday: String): Void =
databaseReference
    .child("users")
    .child(myUserID)
    .child("birthday")
    .setValue(birthday)
    .await()
```

While your approach will work, it will be more convenient to return a `Resource<Boolean>` as in the following lines of code:

```
suspend fun setMyBirthday(birthday: String): Resource<Boolean> = try {
    databaseReference
        .child("users")
        .child(myUserID)
        .child("birthday")
        .setValue(birthday)
        .await()
    Resource.Success(true)
} catch (e: Exception) {
    Resource.Error(e)
}
```

This is more useful because you can pass the error further, otherwise, you won't know if something fails.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was looking for. Is it generally best practice to move the try-catch block to the Repository class instead of the ViewModel class?

Comment: It is recommended to catch the Exception where you perform the API request.